# Filtering out optional matches or results in cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a list of `User` emails and I need to get all of them with their `Team` membership. Both `Users` with `Teams` and those who are not members of any `Team`. I have a query for that which is:

```
  MATCH (u:User)
  WHERE (u.email in $userEmails)
  OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[r:MEMBER_OF]-(t:Team)
  RETURN r, u, t;
```

The problem I have is that I would also want to exclude a list of `Teams` in my query. When I tried this:

```
  MATCH (u:User)
  WHERE (u.email in $userEmails)
  OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[r:MEMBER_OF]-(t:Team)
  WHERE NOT (t.id in $excludedTeamIds)
  RETURN r, u, t;
```

The result was the same list of `Users`, but their `relation` to the `Team` was just missing. I would want to remove both - the `User` and the `Team` from the result.

Comment: You can simply use `MATCH` instead of optional match

Comment: This will remove the `Users` without `Teams` and I want to have all of them in one query.

Comment: So you want all the users with valid teams, or no teams, but not the ones with invalid teams. Correct?

Comment: I send an array of emails `["a@a.pl", "b@b.pl", "c@c.pl", "d@d.pl"]`. A has no account (so no `User`), B has account (has a `User`) but no `Team`, C has an account and is in `Team C`, D has an account and is in `Team D`. I want to get as a result B and C with `Team C` data but without D. I want to be able to filter out `Team D`.

Comment: User To Team is a one-to-one or one-to-many mapping?

Comment: One `User` can have only one `Team`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should filter the users and teams, using an additional `WITH` clause. Like this:

```
MATCH (u:User)
WHERE (u.email in $userEmails)
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[r:MEMBER_OF]-(t:Team)
WITH u, r, t WHERE t IS NULL OR NOT (t.id IN $excludedTeamIds)
RETURN r, u, t;
```

Comment: Omg. You did it! Hats off for you Sir! Thank You very much! :D